# Invalid token at start of a preprocessor expression in CoreFoundation

Tags: ios, xcode, preprocessor, llvm, core-foundation

I'm having the following issue for the last 2 days. Whenever I try to build 1 specific app, I keep getting errors in some of the CoreFoundation classes. To be specific in the classes where one of the macros **TARGET_OS_IPHONE** or **TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED** is used. I don't know the source of this problem, but would be very happy to get some help...

[image: Errors]
[image: Preprocessor]

I am using the LLVM compiler, XCode 4.6.2.

Is this a well known issue, because I couldn't find anything when searching?

**EDIT:** This happened AFTER I cleaned my derived data.

**SOLVED:** For reasons unknown to me the error kept appearing. After building a new clean project and adding all files to it, it all compiled without issues! Very, very, very strange...

**ADDITIONAL INFO:** It had something to do with the fact that the folder was a clone of a repository and it messed something up I guess. After I created the new clean project and it all worked out fine, I placed it in that folder and it started showing those nasty errors again. It had something to do with the folder it's in...

Comment: what frameworks are you currently including in your app?

Comment: Right now I'm including the CoreMotion, AudioToolbox, OpenAL, OpenGLES, UIKit, Foundation, CoreGraphics, GLKit. Nothing more.

Comment: well, now you have 11 rep

Comment: a start at locating it on your own would be to view the preprocessed output. still, it's very strange -- are you by chance including individual headers of a framework (e.g. `#import <SomeFramework/SomeFile.h>`), rather than using the usual `#import <SomeFramework/SomeFramework.h>`?

Comment: I wasn't able to do it, since the project doesn't want to compile. Should I be able to, if it doesn't compile?
No, I'm importing only headers like the following `#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>`, `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`, etc.

Comment: Do you have an import statement inside an interface/implementation tag?  All import statements should be outside any interface and implementation tags (preferably at the top of the file).  Having them inside the tags often causes strange warnings such as the ones you're experiencing

Comment: No, I don't. I tend to keep my code pretty clean. I've even moved all imports to the implementation, whenever possible. I am now starting to project again and importing everything one by one, nothing else comes to mind at this point.